# Swing, Drag and Drop

Tags: java, swing, gui, drag-n-drop

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сделать программу типо Scene Builder, на данный момент реализовал перетаскивание компонентов мышкой и их добавление.
Следующий этап это перенос компонентов между контейнерами, логику я понимаю, но реализовать не получается.
Для теста создал фрейм с JSplitPane, слева создаются кнопки, а вправо они должны перемещаться.

Подкиньте идею как или с помощью чего можно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> UPD

Решил использовать библиотеку DnD, все хорошо, но при перетаскивании компонента на панель с boxlayout все компоненты которые там были уменьшаются, что с этим можно сделать?

[Код](https://github.com/Bleser92/SwingTest)

Comment: Наметки кода есть какие-нибудь? Потому что лучше написать код, который даже не правильный, чем вообще ничего не писать

Comment: Вот то что есть у меня на данный момент, если нужно перезалью в другое место
https://github.com/Bleser92/SwingTest

Comment: Вы нашли решение?

Comment: Сейчас решил пойти по пути использования Drag and Drop, но и тут не все так гладко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать то что мне было нужно, я смог используя  [DnD](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Createadragsourceadroptargetandatransferableobject.htm) и [GlassPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).